Maximum schema length?
I am getting this error when running the evaluate function on my mlflow model:

mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Dataset schema exceeds the maximum length of 65535

However, when I look into the Schema section of my model, it says I have 4749 inputs and 1 output. This is how I configured the evaluate function call:
mlflow.evaluate(
                model_uri,
                eval_data,
                targets="label",
                model_type="classifier",
                validation_thresholds=thresholds
            )

I also checked eval_data and it had dimensions (11336, 4565).
How might I fix this issue?
